# plotting variables from 2 different df together

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Data1 <- data.frame(AGE=c(20,30,15,22,80),
                               CAR = c(1,1,3,9,1),
                               BIKE = c(2,NA,4,NA,9),
                               PLANE = c(8,NA,6,7,9),
                               BOAT = c(1,2,NA,4,NA),
                               WALKING=c(3,5,5,9,1),
                               SCOOTER = c(2,NA,6,9,NA))

Data2 <- data.frame(AGE=c(20,30,15,22,80),
                               CAR = c(1,1,3,9,1),
                               BIKE = c(2,NA,4,NA,9),
                               PLANE = c(8,NA,6,7,9),
                               BOAT = c(1,2,NA,4,NA),
                               WALKING=c(3,5,5,9,1),
                               SCOOTER = c(2,4,6,9,3))
```

I have a data frame `Data1` where I imputed the missing values in the variable “SCOOTER” to get Data2.

I want to do a density plot for the variable `SCOOTER` using both `Data1` and `Data2`. I can do this separately;

```
Plot <- ggplot(data=Data1, aes(x=SCOTTER)) +
        geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white")+ 
        geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="Blue")+ 
        xlab('Data1 table')+
        ylab('Probability Density Function')


Plot <- ggplot(data=Data2, aes(x=SCOTTER)) +
        geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white")+ 
        geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="pink")+ 
        xlab('Data2 table')+
        ylab('Probability Density Function')
```

Is there a way to combine these plots together - so I have the plots on the same frame like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by row-binding both datasets using e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows`. In the code below I add an identifier to the bind-ed dataset which can be mapped on the `fill` aesthetic. The fill colors can then be set via `scale_fill_manual`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- list(data1 = Data1, data2 = Data2) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "id")

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=SCOOTER)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white")+ 
  geom_density(aes(fill = id), alpha=.2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(data1 = "blue", data2 = "pink")) +
  xlab('Scooter')+
  ylab('Probability Density Function')
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
```

[image]